# Rig pose keeps resetting after saving

Tags: rigging, .fbx, pose-mode, saving

Every time I pose a rig(originally a T-pose .fbx from Mixamo), after saving and re-opening the blend file again, the rig pose is reset to the T-pose.
I have no idea what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: are you sure you're creating keyframes ("i")? Please share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You should still be able to retain the pose through saves without a keyframe.  Are you relying on the pose library to set your pose?